# How to block PayPal orders / payments from certain countries (defined by shipping location)?

Tags: paypal, paypal-permissions

I have an ecommerce setup with several Buy Now buttons.

I want to refuse payments from people who enter certain countries as their shipping address, because it is too risky to ship products to some countries.

So far, the best solution I can come up with is charging 9,999 USD for shipping to some countries (a very high amount that people will refuse to pay).

Is there a way that I can simply refuse payments from certain shipping locations?

I tried to do this by excluding the countries I want to block in my Shipping Calculator, but it will just accept these payments with free shipping.

If there is no solution, another alternative I would be open to is blocking all payments from certain countries.

Answer (score 0):

there isn't a way to deny a specific shipping destination; only the payment from a specific country. Unless you redirect back to your site using Express Checkout which you could invoke NOSHIPPING=1; disallowing someone to select their shipping on the paypal side; giving them the ability to enter their shipping address on a review page where you will validate what shipping destination they can select, ect. This is not available from a paypal button or setting.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

@Jason - I had the same question and after numerous calls to PayPal's fraud department - the best answer I could come up with is that PayPal's system does **not** bend that way. You could code or set up your shopping cart to refuse payment from a specific country...

Having said that, you can still add accepted currencies of the countries you want to sell / ship to in: `Money / Manage currencies` area. Then from `Profile / Profile and Settings / My Selling Tools / Block payments` you can deny payments of the currencies you do not hold.

In my case - I want to sell and ship only to the continental US and Canada. So I added the Canadian Dollar currency (in `Money / Manage Currencies`) and I blocked any other currency but orders from Alaska and Hawaii are still going through. To make sure I am not losing money on those orders I created a specific **domestic shipping rate method** for Alaska and one for Hawaii and I adjusted the shipping costs accordingly.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The protection should be done in the shopping cart.

You can pass the order information to 3rd party fraud screening service such as [FraudLabsPro.com](http://www.FraudLabsPro.com). The web service will process the IP address to determine the exact location of user and then decide the status of the order based on your rules. You can configure to block orders based on IP address country, billing country or shipping country.